# Rails javascript database queries

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How do I do a PUT, POST or DELETE call from javascript?

I've collected some data using jquery drag and drop.  How do I then send this to the database?  I think I might be able to use jQuery.ajax but can't work out how exactly.

Any pointers appreciated.

Solution:

This is the javascript that works

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url:    "/articles/8", // should be mapped in routes.rb
        data: {articles:{name:"New Name"}}
      });
});
```

But it doesn't change the name of article 8 to New Name.  Firebug shows no errors, but I still can't pass data to the edit.

The url is the standard update using put url, it exists in the routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery ajax for this: It is a very good way to handle browser requests dynamically with server side code.

```
jQuery('#element_id').on('click change',function(){ // use event as per your need
       $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url:    "/edit_comment", // should be mapped in routes.rb
              data: {comment:"new comment"},
              datatype:"html", // check more option
              success: function(data) {
                       // handle response data
                       },
              async:   true
            });    

});
```

For more details check these links:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

**RAILs code**:

```
def edit_comment
@comment = params[:comment]
// store to database
  response_to do |format|
  render :html 'comment.html'
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
map.edit_comment "edit_comment", :controller => 'comment', :action => 'edit_comment'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I need a little more clarification!

If I want to use this to edit a comment can I use @comment to find the url to the control method?

When I'm entering data, if I want to edit the name to be Edward is it

data: {name:"Edward"}

Comment: i have edited the code to make the comment thing little clear. just try to understand it.

Comment: In the ajax call the data statement needs to include an reference to the object.  I've updated my question with code that works.

Answer (score 2):

For PUT and DELETE add an extra parameter named _method: `_method=PUT`
Rails uses it to simulate PUT and DELETE.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like _method=PUT - I get an error `missing : after property id`

_method: "PUT" isn't throwing any errors.  I haven't managed to enter any data yet - I still don't understand how to pass the data.

Comment: The example was url code not js. In JS you would indeed add quotes. Pass the data in the "data: {}" parameter or the jquery ajax request.