# Looping through rows of data with JavaScript (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, leaflet

I am using Leaflet to add markers to map. The following ling of code is how the markers get added to my map.

```
markers.addLayer(new L.Marker([LAT, LONG]).bindPopup(POPUP).openPopup());
```

Now, LAT (float), LONG(float), and POPUP(string) are all data that are held in my database, in a `companies` table. So I want to loop through every row in this table and pull these three attributes from each row, add a marker and move on to the next.

I have looked up a few things, and I figured [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503174/rails-javascript-database-queries) would be a pretty good start, but I am sure how to alter this to fit my needs.

EDIT: It might be worth mentioning, that this is all done on page load and not with any click or anything of that nature.

Answer (score 1):

There's various ways you could do this.  The simplest is to just call that line of code repeatedly in your view.

```
#in some_template.html.erb - expects @companies to have been defined in the controller action.
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  (function() {
     <% @companies.each do |company| %>
       markers.addLayer(new L.Marker([<%= company.lat %>, <%= company.long %>]).bindPopup(<%= company.popup %>).openPopup());
     <% end %>
  })();      
<% end %>
```

You might need to tweak the formatting a bit.

Comment: How exactly does @company need to be defined in the controller?

Comment: Currently I am getting the following error when I plug this into my view, `undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Yes, sorry, i should have said.  My code expects you to have defined `@companies` (not @company) in your controller.  To get all of them, do `@companies = Company.all`